# PHP Update query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

I have written a PHP class which will update 4 fields of a certain row in a table. The row is decided by a session var 'user' (which is unique). It's not working, but i'm not sure if it is because of the query or the class itself. So i'm first gonna ask you guys if there are any errors in this query (there probaply are) and when the query is correct, i'll see if the class itself has errors as well.

Query:

```
UPDATE tblRegistratie(lengte, gewicht, bmi geluk) WHERE `gebruikersnaam` = '" . $_SESSION['regain-user'] . "'
        VALUES(
        '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $this->Lengte_update)."',
        '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $this->Gewicht_update)."',
        '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $this->BMI_update)."',
        ''".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $this->Geluk_update)."',
        );
```

Comment: Based on how the SO syntax highlighter is choking on unclosed quotes, can you post the query in correct context from your code?

Comment: Also, what does `mysql_error()` say after the call fails?

Comment: `bmi geluk` - if that's one column, you need to escape it with backticks (the space might break the query)

Comment: Are you using the INSERT syntax for your UPDATE query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax for `UPDATE` in MySQL would be something like::

```
$sql = "UPDATE tblRegistratie SET
    lengte = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $this->Lengte_update)."',
    gewicht = '".mysql_real_escape_string($conn, $this->Gewicht_update)."',
    bmi = '".mysql_real_escape_string($conn, $this->BMI_update)."',
    geluk = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $this->Geluk_update)."'
    WHERE gebruikersnaam = '". $_SESSION['regain-user'];
```

Answer (score 2):

The quotes look funny here, but I think your problem is a trailing comma `,` after the last param:

```
''".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $this->Geluk_update)."',
                                                          ^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

Last line:

```
    ''".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $this->Geluk_update)."',
    ^^//fix the double qoute and make it single '
```

Comment: Ah yes, looks like two problems.

Answer (score 1):

This is what an UPDATE query should look like.

```
UPDATE tblRegistratie
SET lengte=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $this->Lengte_update),
    gewicht=mysql...etc
    `bmi geluk`=...etc
WHERE `gebruikersnaam` = '" . $_SESSION['regain-user'] . "'
```

Yours looks nothing like that.

Comment: Phillips Indeed - I missed that entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your where clause after the values you're setting. Also, it sounds like you have some punctuation issues.

Consider the following rewrite for general easier-to-read goodness:

```
$query = 'UPDATE tblRegistratie
    SET `lengte` = "' . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $this->Lengte_update) . '",
        `gewicht` = "' . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $this->Gewicht_update) . '",
        `bmi` = "' . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $this->BMI_update) . '",
        `geluk` = "' . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $this->Geluk_update) . '"
    WHERE `gebruikersnaam` = "' . $_SESSION['regain-user'] . '"
';
```

Also, functions like sprintf() can be your friend. :)

```
$query = sprintf('UPDATE `tblRegistratie`
     SET `lengte` = "%s",
         `gewicht` = "%s",
         `bmi` = "%s",
         `geluk` = "%s"
     WHERE `gebruikersnaam` = "%s";', 
     mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $this->Lengte_update),
     mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $this->Gewicht_update),
     mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $this->BMI_update),
     mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $this->Geluk_update),
     $_SESSION['regain-user']
);
```

Comment: You're right, I did. Thanks -- corrected. That thing was tough to write inside a text box; I should have used a real text editor. :)

Comment: I edited the query and it now runs in sql. However, the class still doesn't work so it means there's also a problem with it. It doesn't give any errors either, that kinda bothers me. I'll be posting a new question about it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

**PHP**

On the last line you have two initial single quotes.

Fix:

```
''".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $this->Geluk_update)."',
```

becomes

```
'".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $this->Geluk_update)."',
```

**MySQL**

Additionally, your `UPDATE` syntax appears to be completely invalid. Have a read through [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html).